# Ajax Wordpress Login needs to be stayed in current page Url without redirecting

Tags: ajax

Currently i am creating a login system based on ajax in wordpress after successful login it was redirecting to homepage but what i need is it needs to be stay in the current page where the user is logged in. Here is my code from functions.php.

```
function ajax_auth_init(){
    wp_register_script('validate-script', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/ajax/jquery.validate.js', array('jquery') );
    wp_enqueue_script('validate-script');

    wp_register_script('ajax-auth-script', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/ajax/ajax-auth-script.js', array('jquery') );
    wp_enqueue_script('ajax-auth-script');

    wp_localize_script( 'ajax-auth-script', 'ajax_auth_object', array(
    'ajaxurl' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ),
    'redirecturl' => home_url(),
    'loadingmessage' => __('Sending user info, please wait...')
    ));

    // Enable the user with no privileges to run ajax_login() in AJAX
    add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_ajaxlogin', 'ajax_login' );
    // Enable the user with no privileges to run ajax_register() in AJAX
    add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_ajaxregister', 'ajax_register' );
    // Enable the user with no privileges to run ajax_forgotPassword() in AJAX
    add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_ajaxforgotpassword', 'ajax_forgotPassword' );
}

// Execute the action only if the user isn't logged in
if (!is_user_logged_in()) {
    add_action('init', 'ajax_auth_init');
}
```

I have tried to make it work by adding redirect url. Even after this also it was not working,

```
global $wp;
echo home_url( $wp->request )
```

Comment: so what is the question?

Comment: @MarkKaplun I need it to be stayed in the page in which we login. It was currently redirecting to homepage we need it to be stayed in home

Comment: @MarkKaplun Please see this 'redirecturl' => home_url(), I have tried to replace the homeurl with global $wp;
home_url( $wp->request ) even after that also it was not working.

Comment: It is a very low quality question which should be easy to answer by anyone with passing understanding of PHP. . You do not do yourself any favor by avoiding to figure this out by yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try following code it will works for you. Please add this in your functions.php for getting current page URL

```
    /*Get Current Url */
 function currentUrl( $trim_query_string = false ) {
    $pageURL = (isset( $_SERVER['HTTPS'] ) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] == 'on') ? "https://" : "http://";
    $pageURL .= $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"] . $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
    if( ! $trim_query_string ) {
        return $pageURL;
    } else {
        $url = explode( '?', $pageURL );
        return $url[0];
    }
}
```

Please replace home(); with currentUrl(); It will surely works.